# Why fetch a collection on a _.each loop reload loop?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have this code in coffeescript :

```
render: (collectionName)=>
  console.log "I am rendering"
  @buildBreadcrumb(collectionName) 

buildBreadcrumb: (collectionName) ->
  i=0
  _.each @urlParts, (url_part) =>
      i++
      console.log('value of i : ',i)
      collection = @getCollection(collectionName)
      if (collection.length == 0)
        collection.fetch({
          success: (collection) =>
            @render()
        })
      else
        @appendBreadcrumb()
```

And I don't understand why, sometimes, i got an output as :

```
I am rendering 
value of i : 1
value of i : 2
value of i : 3
/* STRANGE START HERE */
value of i : 2
value of i : 3
```

This problem disappears if i remove the @render() on the fetch success. It's like the _each loop starts again... **But why?**

And if i put @render on the "complete" callback, everything works fine.

```
render: (route)=>
  console.log "I am rendering"
  @buildBreadcrumb() 

buildBreadcrumb: ->
  i=0
  _.each @urlParts, (url_part) =>
      i++
      console.log('value of i : ',i)
      collection = Proscale.Collections.getCollection(collectionName)
      collection.fetch({
        complete: (collection) =>
          @render()
      })
```

Comment: why are you write render: (collectionName)=> , it should render: ()=>

Comment: in your code you call @buildBreadcrumb recursive..

Comment: Yes, it's because i simplified the code for stackoverflow. In fact i fetch only if the collection is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
render: ()=>
  console.log "I am rendering"
  @buildBreadcrumb(collectionName) 

buildBreadcrumb: (collectionName) ->
  i=0
  _.each @urlParts, (url_part) =>
      i++
      console.log('value of i : ',i)
      collection = @getCollection(collectionName)
      collection.fetch({
        success: (collection) =>
          @doSomething(collection)
      })

doSomething : (collection) ->
```